# Excel: Matching 1500 names (Column A) with Supervisors (Column B) and placing Identifier in Corresponding Column C,D,E,etc

Tags: excel, excel-2013

I have a list of names with their direct supervisor that I am trying to expand upon by showing the employees the next few layers down that work for the list of names.
Column C of the linked image brings back results of 1-7 by matching the list of names in A to those in the column of 7 names. This shows that "HB" works for "SW" but that "SW" works for "ZJ," so "HB" is technically under "ZJ" too. What I am hoping to accomplish is to have a result similar to that shown below (or something that will show the employees under each supervisor). As shown below, in the data there are many names not being searched for but that are needing to be mapped to those that **are** being searched for. At the current count there are 1500 employee names with 7 of them being the ones searched out of a list of 143 supervisors that repeat for the employees.

Names to Look for:  "Fictional names used for scenario"
Sam W.   (SW)       1

Robert R. (RR)      2

Kegan G. (KG)       3

Isiah B.    (IB)    4

Orville E. (OE)     5

Robert J. (RJ)      6

Zach J. (ZJ)        7

```
           Column A Column B    Column C    Column D    Column E
           Superv.      Employ.
              HB        PJ                                 7
              SW        HB         1            7
              BE        JR                      2
              HB        IL                      1          7
              IL        AP                                 1
              BE        WP                      2
              RR        BE         2           
              KG        JW         3 
              JW        JH                      3
              ZJ        SW         7
```

These results would then be used to create lists of employees under a certain person.

Things I'm not sure affects this would be how the name is constructed in the workbook. Example Sam W. is listed as Wilson, Sam in the workbook.

Of course if there is another way to achieve the final result that would be easier then I wouldn't mind an altered format to what I currently have. If anyone has an idea how to achieve this please respond. If there are any questions about more specific things in the workbook that I could supply that could help resolve this quicker also let me know for any future inquiries I may have. Thank you.

Comment: I agree that identifiers should have been placed on them but I have just been put on the project after joining the company last Fall and the company I work for is not exactly the most proactive when it comes to this kind of thing.

Comment: There are personnel #'s attached to each employee that do provide a level of uniqueness to the data but no current tables have been prepared to provide any assistance. The example above was to show a simplified version where it shows that since Column C is the immediate supervisor to the employee, D is the next level up, and so on.

Comment: The question is not clear. What are the numbers in Col C, D, E? How are they computed?

Comment: I gave an example in the question to what the numbers represent. The number 1 represents that the employee is under the supervisor SW. Column C shows that SW is the immediate supervisor, D 1 level above the immediate supervisor, and so on. The numbers are actually what the question is asking to solve for as I am attempting to get a result in this form through formulas if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Well, if I understand what you're asking, you need to normalize your data.  In this case, that means creating two tables linked by an employee code that you'll need to create.

Once you have these two tables, you can easily perform any query and summary report you need.

[image]

Comment: This is something I have been working towards in the background while I was trying this other process but knowing the company I work for and their tendencies I've come to expect it would be unlikely that it would be updated. Systems like this are not used very often at the moment and down the road with changes in employment (new hires, firings, transfers) it could make all efforts mute. They recycle employee numbers to new hires. One thing that I saw was consistent was that there would be an access to a list of names with the immediate supervisors associated with them.

Comment: Since your source data has no consistent employee identifier, there's just no way to do any analyses unless you develop your own offline method.  I faced a similar issue with my company using a large, archaic system that I couldn't modify that used job titles that weren't codified.  But my analyses absolutely required consistent job codes.  So my Excel table has string functions that massage the uncoded job titles into my codified versions.  Anything that doesn't match up gets auto-highlighted to ensure I manually tweak it.

Answer (score 0):

Giving a range that contains the 7 names and next to them 7 numbers the name `AUarray` then in C3 and copied down to suit:

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A3,LUarray,2,0),"")
```

and in D2 and copied down to suit:

```
 =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(INDEX(A:A,MATCH(A3,B:B,0)),LUarray,2,0),"")
```

I think something similar (but maybe a lot longer!) would work for ColumnE but I don't have time for that at present.

`

Comment: I apologize for the confusion in the requirement. I missed the tie between the HB & PJ when typing it into a question but you are correct that it should be resulting the same as HB & IL.